# Galois group of $T^3-2$ over $ \mathbb{F}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

What is the galois group of $T^3-2$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$?

I dont really see a way to find this group. I saw it for $\mathbb{Q}$ but not
 $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: You might start by factoring the polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: What stops you from following over ${\bf F}_5$ the steps you took over $\bf Q$?

Comment: Any thoughts, Uralmok?

Comment: Are you still here, Uralmok?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Since $2=3^3$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$, the splitting field of $T^3-2$ is the same as the splitting field of $T^3-1$.